Apply changes in a sub transaction in Progress
I'm trying to apply changes and release the changed tables in a sub transaction but not yet in the main transaction.
Like so:
MAIN_TRANSACT:
DO TRANSACTION:
    
    // do stuff

    SUB_TRANSACT:
    DO TRANSACTION:
        // change stuff
        FIND testTable WHERE ... SHARE-LOCK.
        IF AVAILABLE testTable THEN DO: 
            testTable.value = "new value".
            RELEASE testTable.
        END.
    END. // apply
    
    // do stuff

END.

But all what progress does, is not apply the data after the end of the sub transaction.
What i tried:
I tried to do it like Tom said here and use a different file with a different session.
// main.p

DEFINE VARIABLE hSubFile AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.
IF NOT VALID-HANDLE(hSubFile) THEN DO:
    RUN sub.p PERSISTENT SET hSubFile.
END.

MAIN_TRANSACT:
DO TRANSACTION:
    
    // do stuff

    RUN subTransaction IN hSubFile.
    
    // do stuff

END.

DELETE OBJECT hSubFile NO-ERROR.

// sub.p

PROCEDURE subTransaction:

    SUB_TRANSACT:
    DO TRANSACTION:
        // change stuff
        FIND testTable WHERE ... SHARE-LOCK.
        IF AVAILABLE testTable THEN DO: 
            testTable.value = "new value".
            RELEASE testTable.
        END.
    END. // apply
    
END PROCEDURE.

But this didn't work, but I also think I did it wrong. Since this did not really spawn a new "_progress.exe" process.
I hope someone can help me.

Another file is not another session. Mike’s answer is correct. Also, RELEASE has nothing to do with committing data.

I always thought a END of the transaction and a RELEASE before that is like a commit.
Thanks for clarifying.

The OpenEdge DB does not support committing a sub-transaction so that it survives a roll-back of the actual transaction.
An AppServer request can be a solution, as the AppServer will be doing a separate transaction. But
a) you may first have to add the AppServer to your architecture and
b) in case you want to undo the work done by the AppServer, that cannot be controlled from the calling procedure.
Instead of using the AppServer, you could OS-COMMAND another _progres session. That may simplify issue a) - but won't help with b) either.

Thank you for your fast answer.
I tried and used it with the OS-COMMAND. It seems to work good enough. The performance is not as good as I thought, but it does the trick.

As Mike Fechner already mentioned OpenEdge will undo all transactions, including ended sub-transactions, during rollback.
I don't know what your use case is, but we had to work-around this with our database log library that writes logging to the database.
Log records of failed transactions were not recorded.
A workaround we use is

write the log records to a no-undo temp-table first.
Outside the transaction save the temp-table log records to the real database records.

This approach still has issues

writing log records is postponed, db records are not available immediately, can fail even if the main transaction succeeded
if the transaction ends in an unexpected way, e.g. stop condition, log records will not be written
large logs take significant time to write back to db

Depending on the use case I'd look at other solutions than the one I just described.

Use appserver
Use a message queue
Launch a separate session like you already did


Thank you for your suggestions. Your problem sounds similar to our problem.
But we have to read the database records from the sub transaction in real time from another program. So doing it like you did is unfortunately not an option.
Right now we are checking if we need a appserver or if it's enough to use the OS-COMMAND.

@SaschaZehringer If real-time is important, I'd look at message queue. We use ActiveMQ to sync between environments.
